# Avoid code duplication over classes

Tags: java

I am writing some classes and all of them implement a certain method they inherit from an interface. This method is close to the same for all the classes beside one call to a certain other function.

For example:

```
public void doSomething(){
    int a = 6;
    int b = 7;
    int c = anOtherMethod(a,b);
    while(c < 50){
        c++;
    }
}
```

What if multiple classes have the function doSomething() but the implementation of the method anOtherMethod() is different?

How do I avoid code duplication in this situation? (This is not my actual code but a simplified version that helps me describe what I mean a bit better.)

Comment: Put do something in a base class. Create as many other classes as you need with overridden `anOtherMethod`

Comment: If `anOtherMethod` takes the same arguments, I'd just pass that function into `doSomething`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate could you give an example of how to pass a function into a function?

Comment: I don't believe that `doSomething` doesn't have the arguments (in your case `int a, int b`... Am I wrong?

Comment: @PietHein Sure. I'm in the mountains on awful reception, so I'll try to get something sent when I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming every version of `anOtherFunction` takes two integers and returns an integer, I would just have the method accept a function as an argument, making it Higher Order.

A function that takes two arguments of the same type and returns an object of the same type is known as a [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html). You can add a argument of that type to the method to pass a function in:

```
// Give the method an operator argument 
public void doSomething(BinaryOperator<Integer> otherMethod) {
    int a = 6;
    int b = 7;

    // Then use it here basically like before
    // "apply" is needed to call the passed function
    int c = otherMethod.apply(a,b);
    while(c < 50) 
        c++;
    }
}
```

How you use it though will depend on your use case. As a simple example using a lambda, you can now call it like:

```
doSomething((a, b) -> a + b);
```

Which simply returns the sum of `a` and `b`.

For your particular case though, you may find that having `doSomething` as part of a Interface isn't necessary or optimal. What if instead, `anOtherMethod` is what's required to be supplied? Instead of expecting your classes to supply a `doSomething`, have them supply a `BinaryOperator<Integer>`. Then, when you need to get results from `doSomething`, get the operator from the class, then pass it to `doSomething`. Something like:

```
public callDoSomething(HasOperator obj) {
    // There may be a better way than having a "HasOperator" interface
    // This is just an example though
    BinaryOperator<Integer> f = obj.getOperator();

    doSomething(f);
}
```

Comment: @LAD Coming from functional programming, every time I see duplicate code, my immediate response is "make it a higher order function!". That's proven to be a safe default so far. I love passing functions around. This solution will require some refactoring of the OP's code though, so it won't be quite as easy to implement.

Comment: Yeah, it is probably a better way to do it, although a bit more complex to someone who hasn't used it before. I also try to reduce code duplication as much as possible, as well; it's just a ton better when there is less code that does the same thing as more.

Comment: I flagged this as the solution as it might reduce the amount of classes I have as well. I will be using into the other options as well to learn from them.

Comment: @PietHein That's why I'd prefer this. Avoiding unnecessary inheritance is always nice. If you remember, let me know how it works out.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I will look further into what you wrote as lambda's should help me write some things in less code. But I managed to fix my issue in a (to me) more easy to understand way that drastically reduced the amount of classes I have (I used reflection).

Comment: @PietHein Without seeing your way, I can't comment, but be careful using reflection. That's a heavy hammer that's only necessary in narrow circumstances. I admit that I'm biased though because I write in Clojure, which makes *heavy* use of higher order functions, so as I said above, I throw them at every problem.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a good example of the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

1. Put `doSomething` in a base class.
2. Declare `abstract protected anotherMethod` in that base class as well, but don't provide an implementation.
3. Each subclass then provides the proper implementation for `anotherMethod`.

Answer (score 4):

This is how you could implement the technique that Thilo talked about in the following demo:

**Main class:**

```
public class Main extends Method {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method m = new Main();
        m.doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public int anOtherMethod(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

**Abstact class:**

```
public abstract class Method {

    public abstract int anOtherMethod(int a, int b);

    public void doSomething() {
        int a = 6;
        int b = 7;
        int c = anOtherMethod(a, b);

        System.out.println("Output: "+c);
    }
}
```

This way, all you have to do is override `anOtherMethod()` in each class that you want to use `doSomething()` with a different implementation of the method `anOtherMethod()`.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your answer and @Thilo answer. And I see the difference in time to response...

Comment: I guess the concept is similar but I show how to do something like what he said in code. I didn't use his answer to create mine, though.

Comment: @zlakad I upvoted an credited Thilo's answer, anyway.

Comment: It's O.K. I don't judge anything. BTW, Java 8+ introduced Functions, and I think passing the function as an argument is more suitable for this case...

Comment: Yeah, I looked up the lambda stuff, but I haven't used it much.

Comment: I was reading [this article](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx) on using the lambdas for method reference, if you're interested.

Comment: I've already read it. The issue here is - I am too lazy! Thanks anyway. Good luck, pal...